# Ubuntu16.04 Internal Realtek SD card reader rts522a still problem

Tags: 16.04, realtek, sd-card

I know there are similar questions and some of them solved, but they didn't help me.

I have a HP Envy 13 with an internal Realtek sd card reader rts522a. It was once working with a clean install but now sd card is not recognized at all, only if I boot to Ubuntu with sd card inserted. I don't know at which point it started to not working again.(It did not work on my first installation, too)

I have 16.04 LTS and default kernel 4.4.0-31-generic. Some users with similar problem on 14.04 and 15.10 seem to solved the problem with new kernels 4.4.x. I have tried a few newest kernels but did not help, although 16.04 kernel is reported working for this card.
--Cards and reader are considered healthy, they are working on windows 10.
--It's also not detected by Live ubuntu from an USB.

edit: `lspci` command sometimes triggers sd card to be mounted and listed. But unmounting, ejecting and using another sd has problems again, it's not fixing anything. A ejected card stays still listed but returning it to sd reader not recognizes it always correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With official kernel drivers update today(11/08/2016) the problem seems solved.